# How do I unremove a file from the Windows Explorer Quick Access?

Tags: windows-explorer

I've grown to like the Quick Access feature in the Windows Explorer under Windows 10, even though I don't always like how it keeps track of recentness. For my Java projects, I use an IDE and it doesn't matter if those files don't show up in Quick Access.

Except that some of my Java projects include markdown files that I sometimes edit in Notepad. When I edit those files in Notepad, they show up in Quick Access. So far so good. If I edit them in IntelliJ IDEA, they don't show up in Quick Access, but I'm okay with that.

I decided to reorganize the project structure a little through IntelliJ, so that it would also take care of updating the links in the markdown files automatically.

One file was in Quick Access but with the incorrect path. So I removed it from Quick Access, thinking that once I accessed that file through Notepad the correct path would show up in Quick Access. Wrong, it doesn't show up at all.

At least the folder the file is now in is showing up on the Quick Access folders. But is there any simple way or even a mildly complicated way to get that file to show up on Quick Access again?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this.

Open Windows 10 Explorer.

Navigate to the folder (file) you want in Quick Access. Click on the object.

Now Windows 10 Explorer has opened the File ribbon. Look Top Left and click on Pin to Quick Access .

That should do it - it works fine here.

[image]

Comment: I see it now, it's grayed out. I click on it and nothing happens. But it does look like I pin folders to Quick Access.

Comment: Make sure you click on the object. It works, but it is not a dark icon.